# Trouble setting up RavenDB in embedded mode

Tags: ravendb

I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/hh547101%28en-us%29.aspx) as a reference and installed both (using nuget)

Install-Package RavenDB.Client -Version 1.0.992

AND

Install-Package RavenDB-Embedded -Version 1.0.919

(The [official](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded) link recommends using **Install-Package RavenDB-Embedded**. But that nuget command fails with the error Install-Package : Unable to find package 'RavenDB-Embedded'.)

But the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Raven.Client.Document;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var Store = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };
            var instance =  new EmbeddableDocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };
        }
    }
}
```

does not recognize EmbeddableDocumentStore. What is the namespace for EmbeddableDocumentStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around in google groups and some experimenting, I got the solution

Use

```
Install-Package RavenDB.Embedded -Version 1.0.992
```

Also if its a console application: right click on the console project-->properties-->

Set Target framework to .NET Framework4 (as opposed to the default .NET Framework 4 Client Profile